# Joomla 4 Plugin displays KML file in Google Maps. How to Print it

Tags: google-maps, printing

I have written a Joomla 4.0 Plugin to display a KML file in Google Maps. It works also in Joomla 3.9

I now wish to add a facility to print JUST the map, not the page on which the map sits.
Please see here for the development, and tests in J4.
http://tdocplus.co.uk/0a_Empty400/index.php/kml-map

For many years I have used Mike Reumers plugin in J3. It works perfectly.
http://tdocplus.co.uk/1a_Empty3924/index.php/reumer-map-test - tho I see the print Icon is mis aligned. On linnpark.org.uk [my hobby] we have a couple of dozen maps.

I am really not sure how best to approach this.
I have found a number of posts - but they are all somewhat old.
I have several tests on the same site -
http://tdocplus.co.uk/1a_Empty3924/index.php/tdoc-gmap-test

Any ideas please.

Richard

Comment: Please post all of your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: This page would be much better received at JSE.  Would you like this page to be migrated there?  Please extend your Stack Exchange account to include JSE and leave me a comment if you wish to migrate -- I can facilitate this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found that the gmapprint() function from earlier Google Maps apis is not included in their current api.
So have given up.
The solution is to create one full width map per page for printing with the user's browser's print facility. It works ok.
Richard